# Amazon Alexa (AVS) on Raspberry Pi - monitor for trigger word?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, alexa-voice-service

I'm following the [guide over on Github](https://github.com/amzn/alexa-avs-raspberry-pi) on building a Raspberry Pi with Alexa Voice Service to ask questions and so forth. The demo Java application has a button for start listening and stop listening. Is it possible to have it listen for the trigger word "alexa" and then send data via the API?

Having it always on listening doesn't sound like very good practice and not great for bandwidth for the user either.

Thanks,
Colin